# Sub-query producing an empty set

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to provide a list of active quarterbacks who play for teams who had 20 or more sacks during the season.

I have information in two tables, one of them is a view(v_active_quarterbacks) which shows which quarterbacks are active, the other is the table team_game_stats.

I created the command that lists the teams that have 20+ sacks.

```
SELECT SUM(sacks)
FROM team_game_stats
GROUP BY team_code
HAVING SUM(sacks) > 20;
```

I now need to connect this to v_active_quarterbacks so that I can get a list. I have tried the following but it just provides an empty set.

```
SELECT player_code
FROM v_active_quaterbacks
    INNER JOIN team_game_stats ON v_active_quaterbacks.team_code = team_game_stats.team_code
WHERE sacks IN (SELECT SUM(sacks)
                FROM team_game_stats
                GROUP BY team_code
                HAVING SUM(sacks) > 20);
```

Here is the view description:

```
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| player_code           | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name            | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name             | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| team_code             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| uniform_number        | varchar(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| passes_player_code    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COUNT(passes.attempt) | bigint(21)  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

At this point I am confused and stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose the sub-qeury should return player_code or team_code, not the number of sacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a an inner join on subselect for team_code and sum

```
SELECT player_code , T.sum_sacks
FROM v_active_quaterbacks  
INNER JOIN team_game_stats ON v_active_quaterbacks.team_code = team_game_stats.team_code 
INNER JOIN (  
      SELECT team_code, SUM(sacks)  sum_sacks
      FROM team_game_stats 
      GROUP BY team_code 
      HAVING SUM(sacks) > 20
) T on T.team_code = v_active_quaterbacks.team_code
```